# C++ cout does not work with the method

Tags: c++, cout

I'm trying to implement a hidden word finder game, it reads the puzzle from the text file and then tries to find out where the hidden word is. However, when I try to make a top top bottom search, nothing appears on the screen, even when I write a simple cout command independent from the method. Here is the code: (Output is nothing btw)

```
bool WordPuzzle::searchTopToBottom(string word){
  cout << "asdasda";
  string fullWord = "";
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int index = 0;
  int count;
  bool a = false;
  while (i < numOfColumn){
    while (j < numOfRow){
      if (word[index] == puzzle[i][j]){
        i++;
        index++;
        count++;
        fullWord += word[index];
        if (count == word.size()){
          a = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      else
        j++;
    }
  }
  if (a){
    cout << fullWord;
    return true;
  }
  else{
    cout << "not found";
    return false;
  }
}


int main (){
  cout << "qweqw";
  WordPuzzle w ("puzzle.txt");
  cout << "qweqw";
  w.searchTopToBottom("DEMIR");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that the output is buffered, and output doesn't happen immediately. Use e.g. `std::flush` or `std::endl` manipulators to flush the buffers.

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview window and do not use tabs when posting code (fixed it for you this time).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 15.4 I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `endl` at the end of your `cout`, like that :
`cout << variable << endl;`
The standard output is buffered and it will wait until you wrote a carriage return to display the line. `endl` add this carriage return.

Comment: "it will wait until you wrote a carriage return to display the line." No! `cout` is often line buffered when writing to a terminal (redirect to a file and `tail` on it, you'll see the buffer is flushed less often), but that is certainly not required by The Standard. Use `'\n'` to write a line break and `std::flush` to flush. `std::endl` does both of these at once, but it is so often misunderstood and misused that I just prefer to recommend avoiding it altogether.

Comment: I added endl statement but only asdasd and qweqwe strings showed up on the screen.

Comment: Did the program ends or is stuck in `while (i < numOfColumn){` ?
The two `"qweqw"` strings are displayed ?

Answer (score 1):

To flush the output buffer, just use `std::flush`:

```
std::cout << "my string to be printed" << std::flush;
```

When you want a newline, just write `'\n'`to the end of a line:

```
std::cout << "my string to be printed\n";
```

or

```
std::cout << "my string to be printed" << '\n';
```

Depending on the implementation that also would flush the output buffer (at least on linux when writing to a terminal).

Generally:

- use `'\n'` when you want a newline,
- use `std::flush` when you want the output to be flushed
- use `std::endl` when you want a newline and the output beeing flushed.

Comment: `std::cout` is not guaranteed to be line buffered. If you want to flush, use `std::flush`. It really is that simple.

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, in general you are right. But at least with linux when writing to a tty, that is line buffered. When doing std::cin, output automatically seems to be flushed, so at least on linux the std::flush of my answer is not really required.